# find and replace a String in vi editor on linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, replace, vi

i am trying to replace String with new String in Linux vi editor

```
:s/totel_email_count/total_email_count/g
```

but getting following error.

```
E486: Pattern not found: totel_email_count
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd guess the reason you're getting that error message is because you intend to replace the string on all lines, not just the current one. In order to search all lines, add a `%` to your command:

```
:%s/totel_email_count/total_email_count/g
```

Answer (score 1):

To find and replace with vi editor type following:-

*Type : (colon) followed by %s/foo/bar/ and hit [Enter] key.*

> :%s/foo/bar/

for example:-

> :%s/old_string/new_string/